# Gazebo and ROS2 roadmap

Tags: ros2, gazebo-11, gazebo-10, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

2 questions on the Gazebo roadmap:

1. AFAIK, all ROS2 variants through Eloquent recommend Gazebo 9. Is there an idea to have ROS2 Foxy use Gazebo 11?
2. Can I run Gazebo 10 with ROS2 Eloquent and gazebo_ros_pkgs?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24155/gazebo-and-ros2-roadmap/) by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 62 on 2019-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

1. The `gazebo_ros_pkgs` that you get from the ROS buildfarm depend on the Gazebo version that is available upstream on [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gazebo&searchon=sourcenames). Since we're planning on releasing Gazebo 11 into Ubuntu 20.04, that should be the version that comes with Foxy (and Noetic).
2. We also [release](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_wrapper_versions&cat=connect_ros) other combinations of Gazebo / ROS versions into the [OSRF packages](http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable/pool/main/r/) as needed. So far, no one has asked to use ROS 2 with Gazebo 10, so we haven't released that. If you're interested, you could make sure it compiles, and ticket an [issue](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/issues) asking for the release and we'll work on it as soon as we can.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2019-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clydemcqueen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3875/clydemcqueen/) on 2019-11-24**:
Thanks for the quick answer! I'll wait for 11 & Foxy.